# webview show blank page after rotate the screen in the status of js alert

Tags: javascript, webview

All
I create a webview project in Android,the code is quite simple:

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);    
webView.loadUrl("url");
```

if I click the view,an alert will be shown;
the code is:

```
    $(".wapper").click(function() {
        alert("ok");
   }
```

It works fine in most of time ,unless if I click the view ,there is an alert in front of the screen,in this time, I rotate the screen,the javascript code cann't be called any more. It seems there is a problem in Webkit.
what's more if i download the html file and apply the webview with loadDataWithBaseURL(),
webview only show blank page after the same steps